# Error when starting rails 3 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm getting the following error when I try to start my rails 3 application. It had been running fine for many months, and then I wanted to stop and start again to make changes, and now I'm getting the following error:

```
[root@Web01 script]# rails server -e production
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find activesupport (= 3.1.1) amongst [ZenTest-4.6.2, ZenTest-4.4.2, abstract-1.0.0, actionmailer-3.1.1, actionmailer-3.0.7, actionpack-3.1.1, actionpack-3.0.7, actionpack-2.3.10, activemodel-3.1.1, activemodel-3.0.7, activerecord-3.1.1, activerecord-3.0.7, activerecord-2.3.10, activeresource-3.1.1, activeresource-3.0.7, activesupport-3.0.7, activesupport-2.3.10, apn_on_rails-0.4.2, arel-2.2.1, arel-2.0.9, autotest-4.4.6, builder-3.0.0, builder-2.1.2, bundle-0.0.1, bundler-1.0.15, configatron-2.8.2, configatron-2.6.4, crack-0.1.8, daemon_controller-0.2.6, daemons-1.1.4, diff-lcs-1.1.2, erubis-2.7.0, erubis-2.6.6, fastthread-1.0.7, git-1.2.5, hike-1.2.1, httparty-0.7.8, i18n-0.5.0, jeweler-1.5.2, json-1.6.1, kgio-2.5.0, mail-2.3.0, mail-2.2.17, memcache-client-1.8.5, mime-types-1.16, multi_json-1.0.3, mysql2-0.2.1, passenger-3.0.7, polyglot-0.3.1, rack-1.3.4, rack-1.2.2, rack-1.1.0, rack-cache-1.1, rack-mount-0.8.3, rack-mount-0.6.14, rack-ssl-1.3.2, rack-test-0.6.1, rack-test-0.5.7, rails-3.1.1, rails-3.0.7, railties-3.1.1, railties-3.0.7, raindrops-0.7.0, rake-0.8.7, rb-readline-0.4.0, rcov-0.9.9, rdoc-3.10, rmagick-2.13.1, rspec-2.4.0, rspec-core-2.4.0, rspec-expectations-2.4.0, rspec-mocks-2.4.0, rubygems-update-1.8.11, sprockets-2.0.2, thor-0.14.6, tilt-1.3.3, treetop-1.4.9, tzinfo-0.3.30, tzinfo-0.3.26, unicorn-4.1.1, unicorn-4.0.1, yamler-0.1.0] (Gem::LoadError)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:761:in `activate_dependencies'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:758:in `each'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:758:in `activate_dependencies'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:742:in `activate'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1211:in `gem'
from /usr/local/bin/rails:18
```

Any ideas about what to do?

EDIT

Here's the Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.7'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'mysql2' ,'0.2.1'

gem 'rmagick'

gem 'memcache-client'

gem 'apn_on_rails', :git => 'https://github.com/natescherer/apn_on_rails.git', :branch => 'rails3'

gem 'daemons'

gem 'httparty'
gem "rake", "0.8.7"
gem "rack", "1.3.4"

gem 'tzinfo', '0.3.26'
gem 'mail', '2.2.17'
gem 'arel', '2.0.9'
gem 'unicorn'

gem 'rb-readline'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger (ruby-debug for Ruby 1.8.7+, ruby-debug19 for Ruby 1.9.2+)
# gem 'ruby-debug'
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

# Bundle the extra gems:
# gem 'bj'
# gem 'nokogiri'
# gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
# gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'

# Bundle gems for the local environment. Make sure to
# put test-only gems in this group so their generators
# and rake tasks are available in development mode:
# group :development, :test do
#   gem 'webrat'
# end
```

I'm not sure what `bundle install` is, I'm fairly new to rails.

Comment: Did you run `bundle install`?  Can you show us the Gemfile?

Comment: Look for the `3.1.1` version of `activesupport` in the `Gemfile.lock`. Looks like some gem might be requiring that specific version.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you made bundle install in your console:

```
$ bundle install
```

It seems that activesupport dependence is not available to your application.

Comment: Could you elaborate please? I ran `bundle install` in my application directory and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Do you really need to force that rack version? I trieed to start a new project with your Gemfile and I'm having bundle errors due to rack incompatibility.

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rack":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 3.0.7) depends on
      rack (~> 1.2.1)

    rack (1.3.4)

Comment: Meanwhile I overcame my problem with a bundle update command. I think you should create a new rails test application for rails 3.0.7; Then compare your Gemfile with a clean one, start with that simple version and comment the other gem references. Also verify your gem versions.

Answer (score 0):

Run `bundle update` first, then possibly a `bundle install`

Answer (score 0):

If you got any error in  bundle install then check if any conflict with a particular gem/version.

Go this website http://rubygems.org/ and check if it need any dependency and version.

I think your gem file is old too, because it missing the both jQuery ad prototype gems(I believe you are using either of these)